# Slow down all UI animations on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa

On iOS it's a simple matter of turning the option on in the Simulator, but how can I slow down ALL interface animations for debugging purposes in a Cocoa application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no global switch to *always* slow animations. But you can use the default `NSAnimationSlowMotionOnShift` to slow down most animations whenever you have the shift key held down.

One way of setting this up for debugging is to add it as an argument to your run scheme, i.e. `-NSAnimationSlowMotionOnShift YES`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for